# [moveit] problem about Cartesian Paths of move_group_interface

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow tutorials in *http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html*,and when i plan a Cartesian Paths for UR3, i write the following codes for UR3:

```
std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints;
  waypoints.push_back(target_pose1);

  geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose2 = target_pose1;

  target_pose2.position.z += 0.1;
  waypoints.push_back(target_pose2);  // up 
   target_pose2.position.y -= 0.1;
  waypoints.push_back(target_pose2);  // left
  target_pose2.position.z -= 0.1;
  target_pose2.position.y += 0.1;
  target_pose2.position.x -= 0.1;
  waypoints.push_back(target_pose2);  
  move_group.setMaxVelocityScalingFactor(0.1);
 moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
  const double jump_threshold = 0.0;
  const double eef_step = 0.005;
  double fraction = move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory);
  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 4 (cartesian path) (%.2f%% acheived)", fraction * 100.0);
  sleep(15.0);

ROS_INFO_STREAM("cartesian path .....");
my_plan.trajectory_= trajectory;
move_group.execute(my_plan);
```

The problem is that the fuction *`double fraction = move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory);`* seems work not well .In the terminal i got the following information:

```
 INFO] [1489330212.136327474]: Visualizing plan 4 (cartesian path) (0.00% acheived)
[ INFO] [1489330227.136626416]: cartesian path .....
[ WARN] [1489330227.461583608]: Skipping path because 1 points passed in.
```

Some problem occur when running the function for 0.00% has achieved as terminal implied.  So it didn't plan out the cartesian path. soi can't see the path in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256803/%5Bmoveit%5D-problem-about-cartesian-paths-of-move_group_interface/) by [kaijianliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29662/kaijianliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2017-03-14**:
I see that you are making tool motion  increments of 0.1 m for each point which may cause some of the points to have unreachable orientation, especially in the case of an arm with a small work envelope like the UR3.

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2017-03-14**:
See the method description [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#ad6b02d15000d5b17c89b15a0f744b47c)

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-12-21**:
hello,I also have the same question.so you mean that the first point of the cartesian path should be the gurrent pose of the robot right? By the way how can I know whether the point I want to put in the waypoints is reachable before I fail to compute the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have worked out the problem. It was due to the reason that i should execute to the start point of the waypoints before i start compute cartesian. And also, I should set a longger time for compute cartesian path to ensure 100% acheved. Anyway, thanks.

---

Originally posted by [kaijianliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29662/kaijianliu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2